# Working with Gazebo9.x instead of Gazebo7 with ros kinetic

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo7, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS developers,

I'm currently working with ROS kinetic and Gazebo7. I want to add some animated human actors to a Gazebo7 world, but i can't, and the reason is that these [tutorials] (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=actor&cat=build_robot) are for Gazebo >= 8.x.
I tried to install Gazbo9 (https://medium.com/@abhiksingla10/setting-up-ros-kinetic-and-gazebo-8-or-9-70f2231af21a). It worked but some of the packages (e.g. turtlebot_teleop "for controlling the turtlebot2 in simulation using keyboard") doesn't work anymore. Can anyone give me some help?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393658/working-with-gazebo9.x-instead-of-gazebo7-with-ros-kinetic/) by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2022-01-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-03**:
It’s not recommended to mix Gazebo versions with ROS1 distros. Not sure why teleop will be affected unless a plugin does not longer work.

**Comment by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) on 2022-01-03**:
Yes, mixing causes a lot of problems.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-03**:
If possible I’d suggest don’t mix them up. Restart and keep separate distros.

**Comment by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) on 2022-01-04**:
Yeah, thank you so much, I've already switched to melodic and gazebo9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @self_seghiri

> Gazebo is an independent project like
> boost, ogre or any other project used
> by ROS. Usually, the latest major
> version of gazebo available at the
> beginning of every ROS release cycle

Source: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_wrapper_versions

However packages developed for a particular ROS distro target particular Gazebo versions so installing different version may work for some packages but as you have seen first hand it creates issues with others, thus is not recommended to mix.

**Guideline:**

- ROS Kinetic: Gazebo 7.x
- ROS Melodic: Gazebo 9.x
- ROS Noetic: Gazebo 11.x
- ROS2 Dashing: Gazebo 9.x
- ROS2 Eloquent: Gazebo 9.x
- ROS2 Foxy: Gazebo 11.x

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) on 2022-01-04**:
Thank you Osilva i appreciate your help very much.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-04**:
Hi @seif_seghiri, please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the check mark. Or voting up. Thank you

**Comment by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) on 2022-01-04**:
Yes of course.